# Why can I not use `function` in type hints, as I can use `int`, `str` and `list`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting

I want to include a type hint for a function parameter that should be a function.   Annotating it as `f: function` throws a `NameError`.   What am I missing?

```
>>> s="abc"
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> def f(s: int) -> str:
...     return str(s)
... 
>>> f(428)
'428'
>>> type(f)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(428)
<class 'int'>
>>> def f(s: int, f: function) -> str:
...     return f(s)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
>>>
```

Ok, comments from @jh316 and @mkrieger1 helped me realise I can use `callable` with lowercase `c` without having to do `from typing import Callable`.
I also note the similar questions which answered this - but didn't show up when I searched prior to posting.

Comment: Are you looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable?

Comment: The concrete answer is: `int`, `str`, `list` are built-in names, `function` is not. See: `dir(__builtins__)`

Comment: Because not all types are exposed in the built-in namespace.

Comment: @John you should **not** use `callable`, it is not a valid type annotation. `typing.Callable` along with a lot of stuff in `typing` is going to be slowly phased out, at least that's the plan. To future-proof, use `collections.abc.Callable`